# Content types are missing in Features

Tags: 7, features

I am trying to create a Features module and include my content types but not all of them are showing when I select "Content Types: node".  I am seeing about 80% of them.  Why would this be?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a distribution, etc., it may be the case that there are content types that are provided by another feature or custom module.  These will not appear in the Features UI by default in order to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Feature located.